# keep ViewModel data on re-creation

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Currently i want to create an app with some sort of registration and payment flow.

I use the [MaterialStepper library](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper) to have one `Activity` with `Fragments` each representing one step in the flow.

The `Activity` has a Android Architecture Component [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) and the `ViewModel` contains several properties for the `Fragment`. I use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) and two-way [Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) for my input fields.
Some data is reused in several `Fragments` thats why i used only one `ViewModel` for several fragments.

When the application is in foreground it works like expected, `Fragments` get re-created and the fields keep their values.

My problem is now when I pause the activity and resume it later. The `ViewModel` itself can get recreated as well and therefore looses its data.

What is a good approach to avoid the loss of data in that situation?
I read in an [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090) that you should store some values in `onSaveInstanceState` (e.g. a searchquery to recreate the `ViewModel`). But isn't that way to much in my situation for ~30 input fields?)

Is a [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) database a good approach to insert/update values in the database when the user edits the input fields and observe that `LiveData` objects instead? (unfortunately i have no experience with `Room` yet)

I would be glad about any help or examples (:

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @kazume Oh, I forgot that i wrote that question =P. Actually it works right now (i had some sort of `init()` function which resetted my ViewModel). I will ask again if i need any further assistance.

Comment: Groovey! Glad it worked out :)